# Disable & resize IE

Tags: javascript

I have a few questions in mind...

1. I want to disable right click on my webpage so that noone can alter
   the source code
2. I want to disable the addressBar as well
3. I wish to resize it to a particular size in the bottom right of my
   screen & with a text area so that when ever I click the button
   inside that webpage all the contents in that text box should be
   copied

I tried experimenting but it doesn't seem to work, javascript maybe has some issues.
I wan't it purely on javascript & HTML (Can't use php/asp), want it to work on IE only, dont care about other browsers....

Comment: 1 and 2 are terrible, terrible ideas.

Comment: -1 for not showing research. What have you tried that didn't work? Can you at least put some effort into writing your question and formatting it?

Answer (score 4):

> 1) I wasnt to dis able right click on my webpage so that no one can
>   alter the source code

Regardless of browser hackery employed, the user will *always* be able to view your source. Nobody will *ever* be able to alter the source code on your server (short of the server being hacked or a vulnerability in your code is found). But, using Firebug (or similar), anyone can change client-side script, CSS and/or HTML.

> 2)I want to disable the addressBar as well

You can't just gain full access of a browser. That would get annoying pretty quickly (think about the potential browser-inducing epilepsy if every site had control over your root browser and did different things to it). One thing that you *could* do is have your site create a popup window that is set to a specific size with specific attributes (hiding the address bar, etc). Note that you may annoy users with this as you'll have to deal with popup blockers and such.

> 3)I wish to resize it to a particular size in the bottom right of my
>   screen & with a text area so that when ever I click the button inside
>   that webpage all the contents in that text box should be copied

I have no idea what this means.

---

Was this post a troll?

Comment: I think it's more likely that the OP is brand new to web development.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the address bar with JavaScript.

However you can disable right click. Note: Anyone with enough technical background to know what to do with the source code would know enough to just disable JavaScript to get their right click working.

[Here's a demo with source code to disable right click.](http://jsfiddle.net/9QWMf/)

Demian's answer has some good insight on what you're asking, I strongly suggest you rethink what you're doing.

Comment: Even if right click is disabled, all a user has to do is go to File | Save As to save the page locally.